# How do I use Perl's Win32::IntAuth to connect via single sign-on?

Tags: windows, perl, single-sign-on

I have Perl 5.10. How can I connect to the server using the single sign-on method? I have to send a service ticket to the server and save the credentials returned by the server.

Is [`Win32::IntAuth`](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Win32-IntAuth) is useful for this? How can I use the `Win32::IntAuth` module in script? I have installed the `Win32::IntAuth` module in Perl v5.10.

Please suggest some solution and test script for this problem.

Comment: You need to specify some details - like which single sign-on system you plan to use.  Presumably, you are thinking of MS Active Directory rather than, say, Heimdal Kerberos?  Presumably, you are working on MS Windows?

Comment: I think you'll need to explain a lot more about what you are doing and how you have already tried to do it.